# UserForm RefEdit - Code to reinitialize range selection

Tags: excel, vba, user-controls, userform

I have created a [Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9ShY.jpg) with several option buttons as part of a larger macro. The UserForm will load if there is a specific calculation error and will ask the user to select a method to correct the error.  One option enables a RefEdit control and allows the user to select a new starting cell (and skip the errors and cells between the current and newly defined range).

I have used the _Exit event to set up some error checking (e.g. to ensure a valid range is selected or to ensure the range is a 1x1 range), but I have been unable to find a way to force the RefEdit control to "reinitialize."  I have tried using the RefEdit.SetFocus method but this is not producing the result I want.

Basically, is there a command I can use that mirrors the act of clicking the dropbutton on the RefEdit control?

`Private Sub RefEdit_NewStartCell_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set UserRange = Range(RefEdit_NewStartCell.Text)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid range selected"
        RefEdit_NewStartCell.SetFocus
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0`

Comment: just a dumb question: when there is an error wouldn't be `Cancel = True` all you need? (i'm sure i got that wrong)

Comment: Not sure, I'm not too familiar with how Cancel works.  Would that just replace this line?

`If Err.Number <> 0 Then`

Comment: `Cancel = True` will just prevent an action like this: in ThisWorkbook: `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean): Cancel = True: End Sub` if you try to close the workbook it triggers the BeforeClose. If (at End Sub) `Cancel = True` then the action will be canceled itself => you can't close the workbook. if RefEdit_NewStartCell_Exit works the same then `If Err.Number <> 0 Then Cancel = True` would prevent it to be exited and you would be stick with the selection till `Range(RefEdit_NewStartCell.Text)` has no error at Exit... but i'm not sure... just try it :)

Comment: Doesn't look like that is working.  When I put `Cancel = True` in there the UserForm just closes and the code ends.

**Edit:**
This is the code I tried.

`Private Sub RefEdit_NewStartCell_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean`
`On Error Resume Next`
`Set UserRange = Range(RefEdit_NewStartCell.Text`
`If Err.Number <> 0 Then Cancel = True`
`MsgBox 1`
`End If`

Comment: Ok sorry... Was at least a try... I need to run some tests...

Comment: Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "real" answer, but a workaround (most times excel crashed using a RefEdit, so i could not run tests... sorry)

Do it with your RefEdit if u want (i have used a textbox):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()

  On Error Resume Next
  Set UserRange = Nothing
  UserForm1.Hide

  While UserRange.Count <> 1
    Set UserRange = Application.InputBox("Select Range", , , , , , , 8)
  Wend

  CommandButton1.SetFocus
  TextBox1.Value = UserRange.Address
  UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Hopefully someone got a better answer soon ^.^;

At least the inputbox will only return a valid range (no need to check that)